# EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL query file location

Tags: postgresql, ems-sql-manager

I am using the freeware version of this excellent Postgres client and I have the following problem:

I made some query using the `Query data` window (those opened when you press F12). Now I cannot connect to the database I was using, but I want to retrieve the query I wrote.

The problem is that I don't know where this tool saves that query and how to retrieve them. I am sure it is written somewhere, because you can reopen them when you start the tool after having closed it, but I cannot find any info about the actual location of this query files.

Can you please give me some suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries and all other data are stored in Windows registry branch [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\EMS\PostgreSQL Manager]. You can import entire branch from registry file (NTUSER.DAT).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. To be more precise, the full path in which I've found the SQL editor content is: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\EMS\PostgreSQL Manager\Forms\DBForms\[MY_DB_NAME]\SQLEditor`.